# How to remove space with css

Tags: javascript, css

I want to delete the space between the select box and the remove button.
Here's the code:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <span>Commande :</span>
  <ui-select name="niveau" title="Choose a person" ng-model="dashboard.commande" theme="select2" style="min-width: 300px;">
    <ui-select-match placeholder="Choisir un message...">
      {{$select.selected.name}}
    </ui-select-match>
    <ui-select-choices repeat="item in people | filter: $select.search">
      <span ng-bind-html="item.id | highlight: $select.search" class="hide"></span>
      <small ng-bind-html="item.name | highlight: $select.search"></small>
    </ui-select-choices>
  </ui-select>
  <span>
    <button title="sup" ng-click="dashboard.commande = undefined" class="btn btn-default">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
    </button>
  </span>
</div>
```

image:
[image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZmVfN.png)

Comment: Instead of an image maybe create a Fiddle or something. You're probably looking for `margin`. Set that to `0`.

Comment: Where is the CSS for it?

Comment: first remove spaces in the code

Comment: Yes definitely post some code here that we can look at. But in short, make sure you have a normalize.css reset, then style your inputs so they have no margin first, then add any you think is needed. By default they will probably have margin set on them.

Comment: From the code you've provided, there is no space between the select box and remove button. (Are you using Bootstrap? I see `btn btn-default`. But even when I add those files there's no space.) You need to provide enough information and code to duplicate your problem.

Comment: bootstrap is used

Comment: You want the buttons border to touch the select box border?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `input-group` class and put your button inside a `span` with the class `input-group-btn`.

As the example from [bootstrap website](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups-buttons)

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">


<div class="input-group">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for...">
  <span class="input-group-btn">
    <button class="btn btn-default" type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></button>
  </span>
</div><!-- /input-group -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as you dont seem to know or have access to the css..

Change this

```
<button title="sup" ng-click="dashboard.commande = undefined" class="btn btn-default">
```

To this

```
<button style="position:relative; margin-left:-5px;" title="sup" ng-click="dashboard.commande = undefined" class="btn btn-default">
```